# Yeoman project in travis-ci failed to deploy dist directory to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gruntjs, yeoman, travis-ci, yeoman-generator

I have a [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) project ([webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp#readme) generator), and with the below travis-ci configuration:

```
language: node_js  
node_js:
- '4.1'
before_script:
- gem install compass
- npm install
- npm install bower
- bower install
- npm install grunt-cli
- grunt build
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: AKIAIOVIOPLVOEVHJUQA
secret_access_key:
secure: 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
    bucket: www.raeprojects.org
    local-dir: dist
    acl: public_read
    on:
      repo: raeprojects/www-raeprojects-org
```

I am trying to deploy the `dist` directory ( created by `grunt build` task) to  to [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). Every thing seems fine except at the deployement stage , travis ci is unable to find the `dist` directory and is returning this error message:

```
Deploying application
Already up-to-date!
# HEAD detached at 114e66f
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (7986ed431f2b3467e1369af81ef95256d352c571)
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-        1.8.11/lib/dpl/provider/s3.rb:47:in `chdir': No such file or directory - dist (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.11/lib/dpl/provider/s3.rb:47:in `push_app'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.11/lib/dpl/provider.rb:145:in `block in deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.11/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.11/lib/dpl/provider.rb:145:in `deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.11/lib/dpl/provider/s3.rb:73:in `deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.11/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.11/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.8.11/bin/dpl:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/dpl:23:in `load'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/dpl:23:in `<main>'
```

failed to deploy

I also same issue with different project generated by [gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp#readme) generator . Here is spinet from .travis.yml of that project:

```
 . . . . . . 
 before_script:
 - npm install
 - npm install -g bower
 - bower install
 - gulp build
 . . . . . . .
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you `ls` after executing the step, which, supposedly, creates `dist/`, to ensure it's *actually* there?

Comment: I did that and find the dist/ dir was created , but figured out latter travic-ci was cleaning workspace prior to deployment, that's why the dist/ dir was not available during deployment time

Comment: dude you should redact your creds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i figured it out that [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/) by default cleans the workspace (removed `dist/` directory) after runing `npm test`. I found an option to instruct travis-ci no to cleanup workspace. I added  `skip_cleanup: true` to the `.travis.yml` and works fine. Here is my edited .travis.yml file:

```
deploy:
   . . . . . . .
  bucket: www.raeprojects.org
  local-dir: dist 
  skip_cleanup: true  // insures dist/ dir not to be deleted after npm test
  acl: public_read
  . . . . .
```